# Forward declaration with relative path

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

How can I use forward declaration for the following header file in which the classC header file has the relative path of FolderA/FolderB/?

```
#include "FolderA/FolderB/classC.h"
```

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing forward declarations with `#include` (they aren't the same thing). Can you clarify your question a bit? What are you trying to achieve, and what's not working?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield There are some header files that when I include them in .cpp, there is no problem but when I include them in .h file, I get some strage errors. I thought that using forward declaration can help me.

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Headers can conflict for many reasons, and you're right that forward declarations are sometimes a good solution (but not always).

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield I get these errors: 
`error C2039: 'CreateMutex' : is not a member of 'global namespace''
error C3861: 'CreateMutex': identifier not found`

Comment: Which file are those errors occurring in? Is it your own header file, or the one you're including?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield It is not in my header file nor in the one that I am including!

Comment: It sounds like it may be a namespace conflict, but I'm afraid it's almost impossible to diagnose without seeing all the original code. If you'd like to post it online somewhere (e.g. pastebin) then I can take a closer look.